# How to slow down the animation in pygame?

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I am trying to animate the rising of the sun. The sun's starting position will be just beyond the bottom right of the screen and on each loop, it will move 10 points towards the top left. I placed this code in a while loop so that the sun stops moving after it reaches a certain point.

When I run the program, however, I can't see the rising sun effect I was expecting. Instead the sun just blitted on the two x,y coordinates I placed as the stop points. I thought it was because my program was too fast, so I tried reducing my `clock.tick` to different seconds but all it does is increase the time difference between the start of the program and the blitting of the sun on the end points.

This is my code so far. There are some other things that I am animating in case the code looks confusing:

```
import pygame
import random
import time

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREY = (169,169,169)
ORANGE = (255,140,0)
YELLOW  = (255,255,0)

pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("First animation")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

colour_list = []

default_colours = [BLACK,BLACK,BLACK]


one_colour = RED
two_colour = ORANGE
three_colour = GREEN

colour_list = [one_colour,two_colour,three_colour]


#starting position of the sun

circle_x = 750
circle_y = 550

#speed and direction of circle
circle_change_x = -5
circle_change_y = -5



 # -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True




    screen.fill(WHITE)


    # animates the rising of the sun
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,YELLOW,[circle_x,circle_y],50)

    #moves the sun's starting point
    while circle_x >=50 and circle_y >=50:
        circle_x += circle_change_x
        circle_y  += circle_change_y








    #draws the road
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,[0,400,700,100],0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,[100,430,100,25],0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,[300,430,100,25],0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,[500,430,100,25],0)


    #draws the street light
    x_position = 345
    y_position = 225
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREY,[350,300,15,100],0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,[x_position,y_position,25,75],0)
    circle_list = []
    for i in range(3):
        y_position += 20
        circle = pygame.draw.circle(screen,default_colours[i],[358,y_position],7)
        circle_list.append(circle)







    # --- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

# Close the window and quit.
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the position of the sun in a `while` loop, and this while loop will run until the condition `circle_x >= 50 and circle_y >= 50` is `False`. Since the screen won't be updated during this time and because the loop will be done in some split seconds, the sun will appear at the target position immediately.

Change the `while` to an `if`, `if circle_x >= 50 and circle_y >= 50:`, then the circle will move only once per frame until the condition is False.

Comment: in case you need that while-loop (for whatever reason), place a "    pygame.display.flip()" inside your while-loop.